# Recall .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to know if after creating the .htaccess file I have to call it within the index page, knowing that the main page is unique (only index.php) and all pages are taken from a database.

The web server that I use Apache.

Comment: .htaccess influences all files and folders automatically, you don't need to call it anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file with filename `.htaccess` is an extension to the webserver configuration (most commonly `httpd.conf`) that is loaded automatically by Apache when a file or script is loaded or executed in the directory, or any child-directories, where the `.htaccess` file is placed.

Furthermore, php scripts (or any scripts for that matter) have no knowledge at all of the existence of a .htaccess, nor should they care. They can be depended on configuration settings however, eg. any rewrite rules that pipe all incoming requests through a so-called front-controller (most commonly index.php), but they do not *know* of it's existence. Any configuration could also be placed somewhere else in the configuration tree.

For further info I'd advise you to read about Apache, or webservers in general, and learn how a common (http) request is fulfilled. It'll give you some understanding of what the .htaccess file exactly does, and does not, and how it is related, or unrelated, to any scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly call the htaccess file from any of the php pages
htaccess rules will automatically apply to all the files and sub folders within the specific folder where htaccess file is placed

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *call* the `.htaccess` file, it is an instruction set to the server on how to handle requests (amongst other things). You should place it in the root directory and Apache will look for it automatically when a request to the server is made for any webpage or other file.

You can also have a `.htaccess` flie in each folder (directory) to control requests specific to it.